# Renderer in ext-js

Tags: extjs

What is (in summary) the function of the renderer in ext js?

Comment: which renderer? The ColumnModel using in the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A renderer is basically the function responsible for showing the underlying data to the user in a fashion or format that looks nice or makes sense.

Some examples might make it more clear:

A date renderer could take a javascript Date object and format it nicely like:

```
January 27, 2011
```

A number renderer could take a number like 2.23535346 and format it to 2 decimals like:

```
2.26
```

A renderer could even take a string like 'Y' or 'N' and instead show it as an image like:

[image: Yes]

Basically, the sky is the limit.

Answer (score 0):

The renderer allows you to format data from a store in any way you see fit. It's a function that takes an data value and can return HTML. This is used to keep code that generates HTML separate from the code that generates the data.

Answer (score 0):

Renderes transforms the value of display field into custom fashion. 
let say i want to display any prize value into dollar

```
{ xtype:'displayfield',   
  name:'name',   
  value:'45',   
  renderer:this.transformIntoDollarConvention 
}
```

here, transformIntoDollarConvention is a function defind above the constructor with a return statemnt .

> transformIntoDollarConvention:function(value)
>   {
>           return value+'$';
>   }